# Having problems comparing strings

Tags: python

I have a couple of files with the following content:

```
562,"TEXT"
...
```

and other files with:

```
562,"NULL"
...
```

I'm trying to get the word between the quotation marks ("TEXT") and write to another file but ignore if it's "NULL".

Here's my code:

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    with open(in_path, "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        with open(out_path, "w", encoding='utf-8') as g:
            for line in f:
                if line.startswith("562"):
                    s = line[4:].replace('"', '')
                    if s != 'NULL':
                        g.write(line[4:].replace('"', '') + "\n")
```

However it's not working as it's always writing the value, even when it's null. I tried replacing `s != 'NULL'` for `s is not 'NULL'` but still didn't work. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You're not giving us a lot to go on, but my suggestion would be to switch from this error-prone manual string parsing to [the built-in CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: Yes use the CSV module, but I think the problem is that `s` ends in a newline, try adding `.strip()`.

Comment: @Alex Or to be strict, `.rstrip('\n')`

Comment: If all lines are `number,string`, I would use regular expressions.

Comment: @molbdnilo Why overcomplicate things? Just use `.split(',')`, or better yet the CSV module as already mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use :

```
if s != 'NULL':
```

Use this because strings s might have space or \n in the line.

```
if 'NULL' in s:
```